# Is GameViewController.swift like the controller and GameScenes.swift like the view (Swift games)?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

When creating a new game in Xcode using Swift, the template creates a GameViewController.swift file and a GameScenes.swift file. Is the right way to think about the purposes of these files that the former (GameViewController) is like the controller while GameScenes is like the view?

If true, why do some tutorials show gesture recognizers (e.g., tap, swipe) getting implemented in GameScenes instead of GameViewController?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could see it like that.

Just check the example code when you start a new SpriteKit-project. If you open the `GameViewController.swift` file you see the following line in the `viewDidLoad` method:

```
let skView = self.view as SKView
....
skView.presentScene(scene)
```

Here you see the answer to your question. The view, which is in your `UIViewController` gets casted to `SKView` and presents the GameScene. So the steps are like that:

```
UIViewController --> View --> GameScene
```

But about the tutorials. It depends on the developer how he handles that. If you compare it to for example an `extension`. You can write a util-file where you put everything in, what you want do re-use or you write it straight in your GameScene-file. Of course it's best practice to create an own file for it. But many tutorials just want to have everything in one spot so it's easier for beginners to understand etc.

But often it's way more complicated to write it in the UIViewController. For example if your try to use a `GestureRecognizer`.

But if you check tutorials like for example on [raywenderlich.com](http://raywenderlich.com) you will see, that these are well splitted.(in the final projects).